# How to Upload Image from Android to Google Cloud (Java)?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jsp

I am developing an Android based application that interacts with the Google Cloud. I need to upload Pictures to the Cloud. I have already developed the code for PHP+Android but I am not sure how to handle it in Google Cloud (JAVA).

Android Code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {


            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

            InputStream is;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data.getData().toString());
            Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath); //BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.gallery);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
            byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
            String ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, 1);
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));
            try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Custom user agent");
                HttpPost httppost = new
                HttpPost("http://umair-p.appspot.com/imageupload");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, is.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Picture Shared", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Exception: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            //Toast.makeText(Main.this, data.getData().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

PHP Code (that works fine):

```
<?php
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
echo $base;
// base64 encoded utf-8 string
$binary=base64_decode($base);
// binary, utf-8 bytes
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
// print($binary);
//$theFile = base64_decode($image_data);
$file = fopen('test.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
echo '<img src=test.jpg>';
?>
```

The above solution is working fine but I need to upload image to Google Cloud. Any help?

Comment: What does "Google Cloud" mean? Do you mean that you want to POST an image to a web app hosted on appspot?  If you've already got a working Android app that does this, then you're pretty close to have a non-Android Java app that can do it?  Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to get a Java web app hosted on appspot to talk to the Google App Engine?  At any rate, I don't understand your question.

Comment: My apologies for the ambiguity. I want you to guide me in writing JSP equivalent of the PHP code I have placed in my post. And also to comment if the way I am doing this is correct or not. Since,I am new in JSP, I don't know if this solution would work.

Comment: Hello comet,can you please help me for android code to upload the image into google cloud storage?
You will be very thankful if you mail me the sample code if you had worked on it… 

my mail id: chavinash792@gmail.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to generate an upload URL from you AppEngine application.

First, perform a HTTP GET to http://umair-p.appspot.com/imageupload

Then, on the server, call blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/imageupload"). Return the URL that this generates in the HTTP response.

Finally, the Android app reads the URL from the response and uses it in the HTTP POST request to upload the image.

Comment: This is only necessary if he wants to use blobstore - if the images are less than 1MB, he may not want to. Regardless, linking to the blobstore docs (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/) would be helpful.